# ¿Como obtener los valores del POJO y agregarlo en la función add, set del data - (RecyclerView)?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Buenos días mis estimados amigos, quiero su apoyo para comprender la siguiente problemática:

> Para que me entiendan quiero actualizar los datos que cargan en mi lista de RecyclerView como remove(remover), add(agregar), set(actualizar).

> La función remove no me da problemas, este es el código con el que lo logre, cabe recalcar que todas las funciones se encuentran en mi adapter RecyclerView:

```
public void removeItem(int position){
  mData.remove(position);
  notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

**El gran dilema es como puedo obtener e ingresar esos datos que recojo del POJO, cuando creo un nuevo registro o actualizo, he encontrado tutoriales que solo hablan de las funciones pero no explican con un ejemplo claro, para principiantes como yo.**

> Para agregar un item, he creado la función siguiente:

Como obtengo los datos del POJO - Datos para ingresarle en la función addItem o updateItem.

```
public void addItem(int position, Datos datos){
  mData.add(position, datos);
  notifyItemInserted(position);
  notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mData.size());
}
```

> Para actualizar un item, he creado la función siguiente:

```
public void updateItem(int position, Datos datos){
  mData.add(position, datos);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

> POJO: Datos

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Datos implements Parcelable {
 private String id;
 private String nombre;
 private String biografia;

 /**
  * CONSTRUCTOR
  */
 public Datos(){
    //vacío
 }

 public Recordatorios(String id, String nombre, String biografia) {
  this.id = id;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.biografia = biografia;
 }

 public Datos(Datos datos){
  this.id = datos.id;
  this.nombre = datos.nombre;
  this.biografia = datos.biografia;
 }

 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getNombre() {
  return nombre;
 }

 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
 }

 public String getBiografia() {
  return biografia;
 }

 public void setBiografia(String biografia) {
  this.biografia = biografia;
 }

 @Override
 public int describeContents() {
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
  dest.writeString(this.id);
  dest.writeString(this.nombre);
  dest.writeString(this.biografia);
 }

 protected Datos(Parcel in) {
  this.id = in.readString();
  this.nombre = in.readString();
  this.biografia = in.readString();
 }

 public static final Parcelable.Creator<Datos> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Datos>() {
  @Override
  public Datos createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
   return new Datos(source);
  }

  @Override
  public Datos[] newArray(int size) {
   return new Datos[size];
  }
 };
}
```

> ADAPTER

```
public class lista extends RecyclerView.Adapter<lista.ViewHolder> {

 private List<Datos> mData;
 private Context mContext;

 private OnItemSelectedListener itemClickListener;


 public lista(List<Datos> listaDatos,Context context,OnItemSelectedListener itemClickListener) {

  this.mData = listaDatos;
  this.mContext = context;
  this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

 @Override
 public lista.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
  //crear nueva vista
  View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.datos_item, parent, false);

  return new ViewHolder(v);
 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

  Datos items = mData.get(position);
  holder.bind(mContext, items, itemClickListener);

 }


 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
  TextView id, nombre, biogafia

  ViewHolder(View v) {
   super(v);
   v.setClickable(true);
   id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
   nombre = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre);
   biogafia = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_biografia);
  }

  public void bind(final Context context, final Datos items, final OnItemSelectedListener itemClickListener) {
   id.setText(items.getId());
   nombre.setText(items.getNombre());
   biogafia.setText(items.getBiografia());

   itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     int posicion  = ViewHolder.super.getAdapterPosition();

     itemClickListener.onItemSelected(items, posicion);
    }
   });
  }
 }

 public void removeItem(int posicion) {
     mData.remove(posicion);
     notifyItemRemoved(posicion);
 }

 public void addItem(Datos datos) {
     mData.add(0, datos);
     notifyItemInserted(0);
 }
 public void updateItem(int posicion, Datos datos){
     mData.set(posicion, datos);
    notifyItemChanged(posicion);
 }


 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return mData.size();
 }

}
```

> Fragmento donde carga la lista:

```
public class ListaFragmento extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
private List<Datos> mItemsDatos;
private DataBaseManagerDatos mManager;
private ListaDatosAdaptador mAdapter;

private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

public static interface OnItemSelectedListener {
public void onItemSelected(Datos datos, int posicion);
}

public ListaFragmento() {
// Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista, container, false);

mRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_lista_recordatorio);

mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

mManager = new DataBaseManagerDatos(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

listaDatos();

return v;
}

public void listaDatos(){
mItemsDatos = mManager.getListaDatos();

mAdapter = new ListaDatosAdaptador(mItemsDatos,
    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(Datos Datos, int posicion) {

    listener.onItemSelected(Datos, posicion);

}
});

mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mRecyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

}

public void inserterItem(Datos datos){
mAdapter.agregarItem(new Datos(datos));
mRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(0);

}
public void actualizarItem(int posicion, Datos datos){

mAdapter.updateItem(posicion, new Datos(datos));

}

public void removerItem(int posicion){
//Remover un item de la lista
mAdapter.removeItem(posicion);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);

if (context instanceof Activity) {
this.activity = (Activity) context;
listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) this.activity;
} else {
throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
        + " must implement ItemsListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
}

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
super.onDetach();
listener = null;
}

}
```

> El gran dilema es como puedo obtener e ingresar esos datos que recojo del POJO, cuando creo un nuevo registro o actualizo.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que cuando se agrega o actualiza un item, se muestren los cambios en la interfaz gráfica?

Comment: Seria bueno que mostraras la clase donde declaras el RecyclerView y también el adaptador de este.

Comment: Ya agregue el código mi amigo @David

Comment: Ya probaste el código de la respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
public void updateItem(int position, Datos datos){
    mData.remove(position);
    mData.add(position, datos);

    ArrayList<Datos> actualizarDatos = mData;
    mData.clear();
    mData.addAll(actualizarDatos);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItem(int position, Datos datos){
    mData.add(position, datos);

    ArrayList<Datos> actualizarDatos = mData;
    mData.clear();
    mData.addAll(actualizarDatos);

    notifyItemInserted(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mData.size());
}
```

Comment: Voy a implementarlo, haber como me va.

Comment: Este código lo voy a implementar, pero aún sigue sin convencerme.

Comment: Pues que esperas, hazlo. Cualquier cosa me dejas saber.

Comment: Como obtengo Datos datos,  `public void addItem(int position, Datos datos)`, es esa es la pregunta

Comment: Para que los quieres obtener?

Comment: Haber me explico el método `public void addItem(int position, Datos datos)`  requiere de un modelo POJO, para poder agregar los datos nuevos esos como lo obtengo o cual seria la lógica correcta.

Comment: A ver no entiendo muy bien tu duda. Los datos los estas obteniendo en el método `bind` de la clase `ViewHolder`. Cuando utilizas el método `notifyDataSetChanged` lo que haces es volver a ejecutar el adaptador y así este vuelve a cargar los datos, por lo que todos los métodos del adaptador se vuelven a ejecutar, incluyendo el método `bind` que es donde obtienes los datos del POJO.